# iOS 16 BackgroundTask error: No task request with identifier <decode: missing data> has been scheduled

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16

I have been trying to schedule a `BackgroundTask` for my app that will refresh a database. So far I have been getting the same error when I try to launch the background task through Xcode

When I try scheduling the task with the following code:

```
e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"refreshEntries"]
```

I get the following error:

> No task request with identifier <decode: missing data> has been
> scheduled

Here's the code that I'm using

```
import BackgroundTasks

@main
struct ExpenseTrackerApp: SwiftUI.App {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var phase
            
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
 
        }
            // background task scheduler
            .onChange(of: phase) { newPhase in
                        switch newPhase {
                        case .background: scheduleAppRefresh()
                        default: break
                        }
                    }
            .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("refreshEntries")) {
                await refreshRecurringEntries()
            }
    }
    
    // Backgroud task 
    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "refreshEntries")
        request.earliestBeginDate =  .now.addingTimeInterval(24 * 3600)
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)

        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule task \(error)")
        }
        
        print("Background task submitted") // breakpoint goes here 
    }
    

    func refreshRecurringEntries() async {
        // code that refreshes database
    }
}
```

Some of the things I have already tried and did not work:

- `info.plist` already has "Permitted background task scheduler identifiers" with key "refreshEntries"
- I have already added Background modes capability to do background fetch and background processing
- I have set the breakpoint right after the background request is made (see code above)

It seems like a lot of people have been posting this error already but so far no one has actually solved

Answer (score 0):

With exactly the same setup as you describe, for me, it fails on the simulator

However, it works on a device.

Comment: I tried using a device and it still would not work. I even tried with different Id's and reinstalled the app